# How to delete the css styles in my wordpress home page head section

Tags: wordpress

I was given a wordpress site running a Fusion Framework and Avada as the child theme. The theme is so powerful, I'v never seen anything like it. However, it is not a good thing for us developers, it takes a lot of control from us. For example, I can't hardly style anything because almost all the css is in the `<head>` section wrapped `<style>` tags. Making all external css inferior to these styles.

As you know, Wordpress generates its pages differently than a traditional website. There isn't a "real" domain/index.php page that I can go to and alter the `<head>`.

I check the Header section in the editor and nothing css related there either.

Is there any way to (I'm assuming a plugin) that I can access the `<head>` section and delete the styles there so I can move them to a css file I can control?

I will provide the page url upon request only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the css is not directly inserted in the head, but injected dynamically. So after looking closer and some more debugging, I found this function

```
<?php
ob_start();
include_once get_template_directory() . '/framework/dynamic_css.php';
$dynamic_css = ob_get_contents();
ob_get_clean();

if( is_page('header-2') || is_page('header-3') || is_page('header-4') || is_page('header-5') ) {
    $header_demo = true;
} else {
    $header_demo = false;
}

//echo $dynamic_css;
?>
```

Commenting out the echo for this function solves the issue.

***!IMPORTANT***

Before attempting to comment out the styles output, do a view source and copy and paste these styles from the head and into your separate css so that you don't lose any of the styles produced in the backend. This keeps the styles, but places them in a css that you can control much easier and your load speed will improve as well.

***!ALSO IMPORTANT***
From this point forward any modifications you do to the styles in the backend will not apply, so make all future mods to the css directly into the new css file that was created or the style.css file as well.

Answer (score 1):

all the css are generated dynamically based on user's selected options.

to add your own css you should try your framework's backedn options panel.

That css will go before  section so it will help to overwrite default css.

let me know if you are not able to do it.

Comment: however you can check theme's header.php file. Most probably you will find those <style> tag there.

Comment: I don't want to use wordpress selected css options to develop this site. Is bad enough it is a wordpress site and I to deal with plugins. I want to be able to delete all the styles from the index page and control them myself in a separate css file.

Comment: Also, the header file has some conditional css calls. Mostly for responsive css display. Not what I am looking for. I'm sure the call for the rest of the styles is there as well. i just can't find it

Comment: most of the style there are auto generated by users selection so you have to overwrite it. You can add you own css right before </head>. use theme function like get_template_directory_uri() and place your site in your theme. call that stylesheet before </head>

Comment: or you have to completely remove the call of that stylesheet. Then there will be no effect of users selection form backend options panel.

Comment: I don't want to add any styles to the head. it clutters the page and increases loading time. besides, it is not proper front end development. I know I have to remove the call, that is what I want to find out here. Because so far there is no direct css in it. It is obviously being injected in the head some other way

Comment: then it can be done from functions.php file or other file included in functions.php. The Theme author is using wp_head action to inject his content in head. http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head
So you have to find it there and remove that call.

Comment: found the call. I knew it was in there somewhere. I'm going to add put it here in solution form so that I can display the code

Comment: I +1 your answer in gratitude for your help. You were not wrong, neither very specific, but you showed you have basic knowledge of the fundamentals being in play here